# Что изображено на стене?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли назвать изображенное на стене произведение искусства лепниной или барельефом?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не уверен, что вопрос подходит для этого сайта.

Answer (score 1):

Произведением искусства лучше не называть, ибо это лишь повторяющаяся деталь (как рондо, рефрен) лепного декора интерьера. Эту деталь назвал бы лепным орнаментальным паспарту. Так же с большой натяжкой можно назвать её картушем, однако по идее картуш — вещь штучная.

> КАРТУШ. (франц.) [cartouche; Kartusche f; cartouche (m)] —
> декоративная лепная деталь в виде щита, полуразвернутого свитка или
> орнаментального венка, где помещались герб, эмблема, надписи и т. п. В
> архитектуре картуши получили особенно широкое распространение в
> XVI—XVII столетиях, когда господствовал стиль барокко.